# If I use echo a lot, should I use output buffering?

Tags: php, output-buffering

Hi this is a basic question, however I'm not sure about it, so I ask you:

If I have more than 100 php echos in my html code, something like this:

file.php:

```
<!-- headers -->
<h1><?php echo $text1; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $text20; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $text10; ?></p>
<!-- more code -->
```

Should I use output buffering ? If so, which would be the right way (or function) to 'show' the output ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Enable it in php.ini and that's all you need to care about. Output is only buffered and will be shown while your script runs (or finally at the end).

Comment: You can write it like this.. `<?=$text1?>`

Comment: @webarto - only if you have short tags enabled.

Comment: `This directive also affected the shorthand <?= before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to <? echo. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.`, but for now, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output buffering is ideal for one primary reason, and it's not to reduce the number of echos. It is ideal because it allows you to write a cache file and serve up that static cache file when it is requested. Then your PHP never outputs directly to the browser, it always writes to files when are then loaded and displayed to the browser. Assuming you set your cache expire headers to a reasonable duration, this will improve performance much more than worrying about "how" you output your data.

Typical case:

1. User visits 'contact.php'
2. 'contact.php' checks for existing cache file
3. If file exists and does not need a refresh, simply display the file and exit.
4. If the file exists and needs a refresh, (re)write all the buffered output to it and display it.
5. If the file does not exist, see step 4.

Comment: Doing post-processing on rendered HTML is another big reason output buffering gets used.